# Class __init__ seems to be starting other Functions within the class?

Tags: class, user-interface

I'm trying to code a GUI with two login functions and then a third window with a bunch of widgets. The issue I've run into is since I want to take entry values and retrieve them from another function, I figured I should use a Class. However, when I'm running my code, it seems to pop open all of the other Functions in the starting class.

```
import sys
from tkinter import *

class Gui():
    def __init__(self, root):
    self.root=root
    self.entry = Entry(root)
    stvar=StringVar()
    stvar.set("one")

    self.canvas=Canvas(root, width=300, height=300, background='white')
    self.canvas.grid(row=1,column=0, columnspan = 4)

    frame = Frame(self.root)
    frame.grid(row=2,column=0, sticky="s")
    frame2 = Frame(self.root)
    frame2.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky = "n")

    self.option=OptionMenu(frame, stvar, "one", "two", "three")
    label1=Label(frame, text="Stock Mean:").grid(row=2,column=0, sticky="nw")
    label2=Label(frame2, text="Stocks").grid(row=0,column=0,sticky = "w")
    self.option=OptionMenu(frame2, stvar, "StockOne", "StockTwo", "StockThree").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky = "w")
    label3= Label(frame, text="Std Variance").grid(row=2, column=1)
    label4= Label(frame, text="Buy Price").grid(row=2, column=2)
    label5=Label(frame, text="Sell Price").grid(row=2,column=3)
    label6= Label(frame2, text="Auto/Manual").grid(row=0, column=3,sticky= "e")
    labelSpace1 = Label(frame2, text= "                                   ").grid(row=0, column = 1, columnspan = 2)

    label7 = Label(frame, text = "Sample Mean").grid(row = 3, column = 0)
    label8 = Label(frame, text = "Sample Std Variance").grid(row = 3, column = 1)
    label9 = Label(frame, text = "Sample Buy Price").grid(row = 3, column = 2)
    label10 = Label(frame, text = "Sample Sell Price").grid(row = 3, column = 3)

class Verification():

def __init__(self):
    ##First Window
    self.master = master
    label1 = Label(self.master, text = "Username:")
    label1.pack()
    user = Entry(self.master)
    user.pack()
    label2 = Label(self.master, text = "Password:")
    label2.pack()
    password = Entry(self.master)
    password.pack()
    button = Button(self.master, text = "Login", command = Verification.verify1(self))

    self.master.title("Stock Program")
    self.master.geometry("400x500")
    button.pack()


    ##self.master.mainloop()

def verify1(self):
    self.root1=Toplevel(self.master)
    self.root1.title("Stock Broker Login")
    self.root1.geometry("500x500")

    ##Broker Menu
    variable = StringVar(self.root1)
    variable.set("TestOne")
    OPTIONS = ["One" , "Two", "Three", "Four"]
    self.m = OptionMenu(self.root1, variable, OPTIONS)
    self.m.pack()

    ##Login for Broker Account
    label3 = Label(self.root1, text = "Username:")
    label3.pack()
    self.user2 = Entry(self.root1)
    self.user2.pack()
    label4 = Label(self.root1, text = "Password:")
    label4.pack()
    self.password2 = Entry(self.root1)
    self.password2.pack()
    self.user2info = self.user2.get()
    self.pass2info = self.password2.get()

    button2 = Button(self.root1, text = "Login", command =Verification.verify2(self) )
    button2.pack()

##        button3 = Button(self.root1, text = "Close", command =    Verification.closewindow(self))
##        button3.pack()

##    def closewindow(self):
##        self.master.destroy()

def verify2(self):
    ##if (self.user2info)=="Name":
    self.GraphWindow()
    ##print (self.pass2info)

def GraphWindow(self):
    self.root2 =Tk()
    gui =Gui(self.root2)
    ##self.root2.mainloop()





if __name__ == '__main__':
master=Tk()
start = Verification()

master.mainloop()
```

The first code I used (Which avoided using this Class) did not run into this issue, so the secondary login window would only pop open if the first Login button was trigger( Which would trigger the command Verify1).

Does anyone know how I can prevent the other functions from triggering? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `__init__` method you are *calling* the methods that you're attempting to use as callbacks, rather than simply passing the function object. EX:

```
command = Verification.verify1(self)
```

Should instead be

```
command = self.verify1
```

You make the same mistake in `verify1` with your binding to `verify2`

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent a couple days trying to figure this out, because this is the first time I've worked with a Class. Thank you for solving this headache!

Comment: @TimothyLi No problem. If this solved your problem, please accept the answer by clicking the big gray check mark next to the answer.